# C# MVC Controller Method not populating with Item from View

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, controller, visual-studio-2019

C# newbie here.

Checked "Passing Data Between View Controllers" but it had a lot of syntax I'm presently unfamiliar with.
Researching more is scheduled for later--for example protocol and delegate designs.

Root:
Making an ASP.NET application. An item from a foreach-populated list in a view is failing to populate in the home controller:

View Syntax

```
<input type="text" id="deviceId"/>
@Html.ActionLink("Add Device", "Add", new { /*id=item.PrimaryKey*/})
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Include</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.include)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item)</p> |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Exclude", "Exclude", new { /*id=item.PrimaryKey*/ }) |
                   ==> <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>Exclude</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.exclude)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item)</p> |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Include", "Include", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller Delete Method

```
  public IActionResult Delete(==>string id)
        {
            var theList = DeviceDictionaryConversion.DevDictionaryDEV();

            theList.include.Remove(id);

            return View("ListModDev", theList);
        }
```

checking to see if this is the right data type for the object from the view, or what other ideas i may not be fully comprehending here. Again, the breakpoints from a sample run show code execution in the controller "Delete" method.

Comment: What part of the code is it failing at when you are trying to call the controller? `<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a> ` or here `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  })`

Comment: specifically the ```<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a> ```

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well one, I don't believe that `==>` is proper syntax....or any sort of syntx for that case.

Two: Here you are saying that when this is 'clicked'

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  })
```

Call the `Delete` method. But `Delete` is expecting a parameter of `id` which you are not providing. Also there is no point doing this `new {  }` if you are not passing anything.

However, if you are wanting this method to accept a parameter as well as no parameter you can assign the parameter a value such as:

```
 public IActionResult Delete(string id = "")    // Set to empty string
```

Instead of `<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>` have you tried using `@Url.Action()`? I find this much simpler as all you would need to do is:

```
@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new {id = @item})    // Assuming that `@item` is a string
```

IE

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new {id = @item})" class="btn btn-danger">
```

Comment: I did actually resolve the issue by switching the controller delete method to be a GET instead of a POST. Your answer was helpful. I apologize for not fully fleshing out my question.

Answer (score 0):

So the error appears to be in the type of HTTP method used to handle the Controller Delete.

Switching to GET from POST solved the issue.